# SQLAlchemy raises TypeError when an INSERT returns no rows?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I've got an insert statement like this:

```
insert = MyTable.insert()
row = {"foo": 42}
result = cxn.execute(insert, row)
```

But a Postgres trigger is redirecting inserts from `mytable` to a new table, so the insert statement doesn't actually return anything:

```
# INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (DEFAULT, 'stuff') RETURNING LASTVAL();
 lastval 
---------
(0 rows)
```

This causes SQLAlchemy (0.8b2) to raise a `TypeError: 'NoneType' is not subscriptable`. It looks like this is happening when the `DefaultExecutionContext` tries to fetch the primary key of the inserted row.

Is this a bug that should be reported? And is there any way I can work around this, telling SQLAlchemy not to expect a return value?

#### The traceback

```
… snip… 
  File "myfile.py", line 85, in store
    result = cxn.execute(insert, row)
  File ".../sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 664, in execute
    params)
  File ".../sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 764, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File ".../sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 899, in _execute_context
    context._fetch_implicit_returning(result)
  File ".../sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 697, in _fetch_implicit_returning
    ipk.append(row[c])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

#### The Postgres trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytable_insert_trigger()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mytable_cur VALUES (NEW.*);
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER mytable_insert_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE mytable_insert_trigger();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah, you can fall back to the old system of obtaining the last inserted id by turning off implicit_returning, which you can do for the Table:

```
Table('sometable', metadata, ... columns ..., implicit_returning=False)
```

what will happen there is, assuming this is a straight up SERIAL primary key, it will execute "tablename_id_seq" explicitly beforehand and just use that value in the INSERT statement.

Answer (score 2):

You broke the contract here.  Against a Postgres backend, SQLAlchemy will tend to use `INSERT ... RETURNING` so that it can retrieve e.g. values from generated sequences.  You're inserting a row but lying about it.

Based on [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/plpgsql-trigger.html), I think you want to use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger rather than `BEFORE`, and have it return the `NEW` row unchanged.  Postgres will assume you did whatever inserting is necessary, and merely shuttle the returned row back to the client.

Comment: `INSTEAD OF` would be ideal… But I'm stuck on Postgres 8.4, so it's not an option :(